# query with multiple count statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to combine the following two queries, so that I end up with three columns: RelativePath, field = null/empty string, field with value.  I can execute the queries individually, but I'm having trouble combining them.

```
SELECT RELATIVEPATH, COUNT(RELATIVEPATH) FROM APP 
       WHERE (FIELD IS NULL) OR (FIELD = '')
       GROUP BY (RELATIVEPATH);

SELECT RELATIVEPATH, COUNT(RELATIVEPATH) FROM APP
       WHERE (FIELD IS NOT NULL) 
       GROUP BY (RELATIVEPATH);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the `case` statement:

```
SELECT RELATIVEPATH, sum(case when (FIELD IS NULL) OR (FIELD = '') then 1 else 0 end),
       sum(case when field is not null then 1 else 0 end)
FROM APP 
GROUP BY (RELATIVEPATH);
```

This is assuming that the intention of `count(RelativePath)` is to count all the rows.  If you really want to count the non-NULL values of the column, you would use:

```
SELECT RELATIVEPATH, count(case when (FIELD IS NULL) OR (FIELD = '') then RelativePath end),
       count(case when field is not null then RelativePath end)
FROM APP 
GROUP BY (RELATIVEPATH);
```

Comment: Probably need an "AND FIELD <> '' " in that 2nd CASE statement.